# what are the implementations of openGL available for mac osX?

Tags: macos, macports, opencl

OpenGL is the specifications standards for 2D , 3D graphics.

As of my little knowledge ,

Mesa3D is implementation for openGL on windows and linux platform.

what about macOSX ? what are the implementations of openGL available for macosx?

Comment: [I believe Apple writes it along with the rest of the device drivers in cooperation with the OEMs](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/), though what open source components (if any) it draws from I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL implementation for MacOS is MacOS — OpenGL support is built in. https://developer.apple.com/opengl/